# Convert entire folder to greyscale using image magick?

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert an entire folder to grayscale, using image magick.

```
convert *.jpg -colorspace Gray -separate -average
```

is met with this error :

```
convert:  `-average' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3290.
```

What is the correct command for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have lots of files to process, use `mogrify`:

```
magick mogrify -colorspace gray *.jpg
```

If you have tens of thousands of images and a multi-core CPU, you can get them all done in parallel with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel -X magick mogrify -colorspace gray ::: *.jpg
```

Comment: You are a wizard. Thank you so much. I have been trying slightly different versions of this command for about 2hrs.

Comment: You're welcome. Come back if you get stuck again, questions (and answers) are free :-) Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks; `mogrify -colorspace gray *.jpg` (without `magick` before it - don't know what it is) works just fine.

Comment: @Sadi Your command is old v6 ImageMagick syntax. Mine is newer v7.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the following can be used in a script - for the context menu of file managers like Dolphin, Nautilus, Nemo, Thunar etc:

```
for filename in "${@}"; do
    name="${filename%.*}"
    ext="${filename##*.}"
    cp "$filename" "$name"-grayscale."$ext"
    mogrify -colorspace gray "$name"-grayscale."$ext"
    rm "$name"-grayscale."$ext"~
done
```